# using mc55 with stm32f10x

Tags: gsm, stm32

I'm working on gsm with siemens family device mc55 via stm32f10x. But,I cannot find any simple code or example about initiate mc55 on stm32f10x.
Has anybody run into this in the past? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.